# Как из List<Integer[]> получить значения

Tags: java, массивы, spring, list

У меня есть запрос который возвращает `List<Integer[]>`. Как из этого листа вытянуть может быть в какой-нибудь массив значения, которые хранятся в нем. `list.get(0)` возвращает `[Ljava.lang.Integer;@3ca895e8`.

```java
public List<Integer[]> getRation() {
    List<Integer[]> list = dishRepository.findRation();
    return list;
}

public interface DishRepository extends JpaRepository<Dish, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select d1.id as q,d2.id as qq,d3.id as qqq from dishes d1,dishes d2,dishes d3" +
            " where d1.type='breakfast' and d2.type='dinner' and d3.type='dinner'\n" +
            "and d1.diet='vegan' and d2.diet='vegan' and d3.diet='vegan'\n" +
            "and d1.calories + d2.calories + d3.calories < 1900\n" +
            "and d1.calories + d2.calories + d3.calories > 1800 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Integer[]> findRation(int x, int xx);
}
```

[image: Лист содержит 3 Integer]

Comment: Прошу прощения, если у вас тип `List<Integer[]>`, то вы хотите сделать `flatten`-операцию? `[1, 2], [3], [4] => [1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: list.stream().flatMap(arr->Stream.of(arr)).collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обойти элементы *листа массивов* `List<Integer[]>`, можно использовать метод [`stream.flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-). Потом можно собрать их в массив `int[]` или в лист `List<Integer>`:

```java
List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
list.add(new Integer[]{4, 5});

int[] arr = list.stream()
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

List<Integer> list2 = list.stream()
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list2); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте проитерировать

```java
for (int[] array : List) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```